# iOS 5 autorotation not working

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, autorotate

I have tab bar application and I have a problem with the rotation. I am using a storyboard with the tab bar controller as a initial view controller and on ios 6 everything works and views rotate to landscape and portrait, but on ios 5 views are only in portrait mode and rotation does not working.
I tried to create custom tab bar controller subclass and I added shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation function to it, and also to all view controllers in the tab bar but it didn't help.
Has someone any idea what can be wrong?

Edit:
If you have Xcode 4.5.2 you can create new project from tab bar application template and check yourself whether you have the same problem.

Comment: Autorotation works entirely differently between iOS 5 and iOS 6.  You must essentially code everything twice.

Comment: show us your `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: This is my function:
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

Comment: What code should I provde? If I create a clean new project from tab bar application template and I don't add anything then on ios 6 works, on ios 5 not.

Comment: @HeWas how should I do it? As I wrote, when I added shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation function to all controllers it didn't help on ios 5, on ios 6 still working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that post and that solution works for me:
http://iosgems.blogspot.de/2012/11/how-to-get-autorotation-working-for.html

Answer (score 2):

Check that this is in *EVERY* view controller in your app

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

But don't worry about subclassing the tab bar controller, you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: Yes, I have it in the every view controller.